# Pass data to all routes?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I use a set of data on every route. Is there a way to pass this data to **all** routes without having to specify the data under each route, like:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    $data = Data::all();

    return View::make('index')->with('data', $data);
});

Route::get('/another', function()
{
    $data = Data::all();

    return View::make('another')->with('data', $data);
});
```

Comment: You are passing data to views, not to routes – just to be clear! While it's possible with methods described below, I don't think it's a very good idea to make Eloquent data publicly available like that. Some basic setting like current language – that would be a good candidate. Just think about it – even if one of your routes doesn't need database at all (static page for example), because of your $data variable it will make a DB query. It's unsafe too. If you absolutely want this, make it at least a routing group so that only specific routes get this variable pre-filled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `view()->share()` in a service provider, like so :

```
view()->share('key', 'value');
```

You will then be able to access `value` using `{{ key }}` in all your views.

You can put it in the `boot()` method of the default `AppServiceProvider`.

Answer (score 3):

Use *[view composers](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#view-composers)*.

```
View::composer('profile', function($view)
{
    $view->with('count', User::count());
});
```

> Now each time the `profile` view is rendered, the `count` data will be bound to the view.

Also you need assign composer to many views, so you can just use `['profile', 'dashboard']` instead of `'profile'`.

Or you can [share a data](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#views) with one function:

```
View::share('name', 'Steve');
```